# ESP-WROOM-02 SPI flash reserved pins

Tags: pwm, esp8266, flash, pinout

I’m using some ESP-WROOM-02 modules I had lying around for the first time and I’m a little confused about the included SPI flash IC as part of the module and was hoping someone that has used it could clarify for me. I’d like to do OTA updates to the device once I am done as I plan on installing in ways that are not super accessible and thus the OTA would be of most benefit. This is why I want to make sure I have the pins clarified before I have any PCBs made.

On the module schematics page, it seems to indicate that pins 18-23 of the ESP8266EX are connected to the included SPI IC.
However in the interface description table, it states that IO12-15 “Connects to SPI Flash, display screen, and MCU”. This seems to marry up with what’s in the datasheet for the ESP8266EX.

Can someone clarify if I use IO12-15, can I still access the SPI flash for OTA?

Also I'm confused as the ESP8266EX datasheet says PWM is on IO12, 14, 15 and 4 and the ESP-WROOM-02 says it is on IO12, 13 and 15 yet the schematics show the pins are mapped the same between standalone IC and the module (IO12 > IO12 etc.)

Comment: esp8266 doesn't have an internal flash. the application is stored in and executed from that external flash. the io pin numbering is not the same as the physical package pin numbering